# How to install SQL Developer on macOS Catalina 10.15?

Tags: oracle, javafx, oracle-sqldeveloper, macos-catalina

I've downloaded and unpacked Oracle's SQL Developer 19.4 on macOS 10.15 Catalina. During the first start up, the usual warning appears, which I clicked away as I do since a number of years:
[image: java1.8.0_45 not supported]

SQL Developer starts ok. When creating a new connection to an Oracle database, I enter all the detail and it works fine (the 'Test' button says it's ok), but I cannot save the connection.

JeffSmith said in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61827688/sql-developer-doesnt-display-xml#comment109360563_61827688) that SQL Developer needs JCE jars, which are not in older JDKs, version jkd8u200+ should be fine. To get a newer JDK, I tried homebrew (as this was the only way I could get sqlplus to work on catalina):

```
brew tap adoptopenjdk/openjdk
brew cask install adoptopenjdk8
```

This works, `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` shows now `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home`, and I can create and save connections (Yeah!). However, on start up, SQL Developer complains that JavaFX is missing:

[image: JavaFXmissing]

So I've followed the instructions on [Using Java SE on macOS Catalina](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/using-jdk-jre-macos-catalina-5781620.html), which installs a JRE in `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home`!

Pointing `.sqldeveloper/19.4.0/product.conf` to that JRE causes SQL Developer not starting up at all.

I'm pretty sure that this is not the fault of the SQL Developer team, rather a fight between Apple and Oracle, but why on earth is this such a mess?

Can anybody help here with a clean install instruction?

Comment: OpenJDK never came with JavaFX included: you should probably try to install an Oracle JDK version 8. These are still available from https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html (currently version 1.8.0_251)

Comment: We don't support OpenJDK, Oracle JDK 8 or 11 is what we recommend, the latest update of each

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize the comments, both [Oracle JDK 8](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html) and [Amazon Corretto 8](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/corretto/latest/corretto-11-ug/what-is-corretto-11.html) seem to work. Corretto is easier to install, but not supported. Oracle's JDK is a bit more difficult to install, but there is a [page](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/using-jdk-jre-macos-catalina-5781620.html) explaining how to do it.

I couldn't get SQL Developer to pick up the right Java version, but an entry in `.sqldeveloper/19.4.0/product.conf` got everything working

```
SetJavaHome /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_251.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Thanks for the help!